# RxSwift pointfree style avoid retain cycles

Tags: swift, rx-swift

Im wondering if i can use pointfree-style using Swift/RxSwift like so:

```
class MyClass {
   private let ageService: Observable<Int> = AgeService()
   private let userService: Observable<Bool> = UserService()

    func test() ->  Observable<Int>{
       return userService
                  .getRandomUser()
                  .flatMap(self.networkService.ageFromUser)
    }
```

Or should i go always with .. ?

```
func test2() ->  Observable<Int>{
   return userService.getRandomUser().flatMap { [weak self] user in
       guard let strongSelf = self else { return .empty() }
       return strongSelf.networkService.ageFromUser(user) 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When working with closures when you are pointing to self inside closure like in your case of flapmap the retain cycle gets created if you DON'T use [weak/unowned self].

So its developer responsibility to avoid these kind of retain cycles. So whenever you have reference for self inside any closure try to use weak / unowned as per scope. In your case go for second i.e test2 function.

Hope out helps ...!!!